# O prazo para poder oferecer uma recompensa é bom?

Tags: debate, recompensa

Fiz uma pergunta ontem, não obtive respostas e pensei em oferecer uma recompensa. Porém só poderei oferecer uma recompensa amanhã. Baseado nisso suponho que são dois dias para poder oferecer uma recompensa.

Já fiz diversas perguntas no site e as perguntas geralmente são respondidas no prazo de 1 dia no máximo (na maioria das vezes em minutos), ou então acabam ficando um pouco esquecidas.

Entendo perfeitamente que o prazo ajuda a não virar uma bagunça de recompensas, mas na minha opinião 1 dia apenas já seria o suficiente.

O que vocês acham?

Comment: Acho que o prazo é pensado para inibir a "terceirização de trabalhos urgentes via recompensas" e forçar o usuário a buscar solução por sua própria conta. {citation needed}

Comment: Só uma dica, mudando de assunto: Acho que talvez vale a pena você tentar editar a pergunta e principalmente o título, pois muitas vezes o problema esta nisto, claro que recompensas podem ajudar. No entanto já vi perguntas com recompensas com recompensa alta e ninguém respondeu. Se for esta pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91445/3635 realmente não tem muito o que editar.

Comment: @brasofilo Táí uma coisa que não acho certa, porque que não é algo objetivo, tem um julgamento moral envolvido aí. O usuário ganhou a reputação, o que não é nada fácil por aqui, e limitar o que ele pode fazer com ela sob a justificativa de que deveria antes "procurar por si" é um preconceito moral (ah esse cara é o típico sanguessuga e tal...) ... Meu ponto é: como é que alguém pode saber se a pessoa pesquisou ou não?  Se procurou por si ou não? Se por algum motivo uma resposta pra mim é importante pra ontem, quem é que pode julgar se eu pesquisei ou não???

Comment: Mas justamente @brasofilo, o que vai resolver isso é a qualidade da pergunta. Existem mecanismos pra coibir perguntas ruins, feitas obviamente sem pesquisa nenhuma, e acho que tornar o tempo mais longo pra oferecer recompensas é desnecessário, e prejudicial pra quem se dedica ao site. Até porque, quem tem reputação pra oferecer recompensa em geral sabe fazer uma pergunta (sempre vão existir os absurdos, tbm já vi alguns...).

Comment: @gustavox, fiz uma resposta detalhada

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2621/3635

Answer (score 12):

Eu interpreto a justificativa oficial para o prazo de dois dias como *"Está com pressa? Contrate um desenvolvedor"* ou até *"Sem resposta? Pesquise um pouco mais e acrescente detalhes na pergunta"*.

Essa justificativa é dada [por um dos moderadores do Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat/3333#3333) a uma pergunta que pede a eliminação de qualquer prazo para oferecer uma recompensa:

> Nos Podcasts [#26](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/podcast-26/) and [#34](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/podcast-34/), Joel e Jeff <sup>*</sup> falaram a respeito disso. Eles não queriam que o sistema de recompensas interferisse com o método "normal" de perguntar e responder. Se houver possibilidade de oferecer uma recompensa imediatamente, então aparece o potencial de criar uma economia onde as pessoas focalizam somente em perguntas com recompensas.

<sup>* fundadores do site</sup>
Vejo o "método normal" como responder grátis e voluntariamente a perguntas interessantes e desafiadoras, motivado por razões pessoais e pelo sistema de gamificação do site que é muito viciante, conforme [confessa o próprio Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W25802) (enfase minha):

> *People come in and help you fix your question, and it feels good.  It feels good to help other people, I don't know why.  It's really--it's addictive.  Even I, having built the system I'm frankly a little bit sick of it at this point just because I'm doing it all day every day, but I still get totally sucked into it.  I'll spend hours, literally, just clicking around Stack Overflow, editing stuff, looking at stuff, learning stuff.  **The system is incredibly addictive, even to me**, so I guess that's fair since I was--we were the target audience.  So I guess it would be a failure if that was not true.  But I enjoy using the system, for what it's worth.*

---

Concordo também com os pontos levantados [nesta resposta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/why-cant-i-just-offer-a-bounty-for-a-question-right-off-the-bat/176360#176360):

- o fato da pessoa ter pontos para gastar não deve lhe dar mais vantagens que quem não tem ([o mínimo para oferecer uma recompensa são 75 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties));
- *a maneira correta de atrair atenção para sua pergunta é gastar mais tempo escrevendo uma pergunta que é clara, concisa e bem pesquisada. Perguntas de alta qualidade são votadas positivamente, o que aumenta sua visibilidade, aumenta a chance de receber respostas sólidas, e aumenta a reputação ao mesmo tempo.*
- recompensas oferecem um incentivo a perguntas obscuras ou dificeis, mas só devem ser oferecidas depois que o tempo provou que o incentivo extra é necessário.

Tem um outro argumento que aparece [nesta outra pergunta pedindo o prazo de um dia](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51555/how-to-set-a-bounty-on-a-day-old-question):

- um prazo curto pode interferir com o fechamento de perguntas já que oferecer uma recompensa bloqueia os votos para fechamento e precisa da intervenção <sup>*</sup> de um moderador para fechar uma pergunta descaradamente fora de escopo.

<sup>* Enquanto não tem intervenção, sempre tem aquele incauto que vem e responde.</sup>

---

Para finalizar, sobre a questão da reputação de um usuário implicar qualidade nas suas publicações e portanto mais privilégios.

Os privilégios que a gente recebe por fazer boas perguntas e respostas são de *moderação do site*: editar, votar para fechar ou abrir, participar das filas de análise, ver estatísticas e relatórios exclusivos.

Sim, se tenho 10 mil pontos é muito fácil oferecer uma recompensa de 500 pontos para um problema que preciso muito solucionar, mas só depois do prazo regulamentar.

Comment: Então, favoritei aqui essa pergunta, e quando der vou postar uma resposta fundamentada, mas já quero dizer o seguinte: este pensamento "Está com pressa? Contrate um desenvolvedor"  não faz nenhum sentido nenhum, já que a comunidade é formada em geral por desenvolvedores (o AP é um... e p fvr  resista à tentação de pensar em mim como exemplo, estamos falando em tese) e para desenvolvedores. Em tempo: e entusiastas claro!

Comment: Será que um desenvolvedor experiente jamais iria utilizar a exposição da recompensa para auxiliá-lo com um problema urgente? E isso é errado? Somente se houver um julgamento moral, baseado na especulação.

Comment: Uai, o site aqui não foi feito para demandas "urgentes". Sempre que alguém coloca isso no título ou na pergunta, tasco -1 só pela falta de respeito (nunca vi acontecer aqui, só no SOen).

Comment: Conheço a posição da empresa porque navego por todos os cantos, mas não sou afiliado, só fã :) Me parece que tem uma argumentação extensa a fazer à respeito do assunto e que merece com certeza uma resposta completa.

Comment: Acho que tenho mesmo, mas  não vai ser tão logo... e um dia ainda quero escrever aqui no meta algo como uma "Apologia ao novato" em forma de pergunta, baseado na minha experiência surreal com o site. :-) +1

Comment: *"Está com pressa? Contrate um desenvolvedor"* +1

Answer (score 2):

> "Está com pressa? Contrate um desenvolvedor"

Este será o foco da minha resposta, porque em nenhum dos links postados nesta página esta justificativa está presente (nem de longe), mas, a notar pela votação na resposta do @brasofilo e em alguns comentários, muita gente pensa assim.

## E isto está errado.

Primeiro (mas não é o principal argumento) acontece que todos aqui são desenvolvedores. TODOS. Bons ou ruins, podem ser grandes desenvolvedores ou podem estar tentando criar o primeiro site ou um programa... não importa! Você pode ser um ótimo ou um péssimo desenvolvedor, mas não deixará de ser um desenvolvedor.

Então, partindo do pressuposto de que todos são desenvolvedores, qual a justificativa pra impedir a recompensa rápida (instantânea seria o ideal imho)?

**PRECONCEITO!**

Parte-se do pressuposto de que quem precisa de ajuda urgente não é desenvolvedor, e deveria, então, contratar um. Ora, mas que bobagem!

Qualquer um aqui, mesmo o .... ou o ... ou até o .... rsrsrs, pode um dia precisar de uma reposta pra algo que não domina totalmente, **esta resposta pode não existir aqui**, o **assunto estar dentro do escopo**, e a pergunta pode **passar por todas as exigências pra não ser fechada ou suspensa**... e mesmo assim será preciso esperar 48 horas pra oferecer a recompensa.

Mas pois, que absurdo!

É claro que se você for um gênio a probabilidade disso acontecer é menor, afinal você pode saber tudo, ou contactar quem saiba, sem precisar oferecer recompensa nenhuma.

Mas e as pessoas que como você contribuem (na medida de suas possibilidades) com o site,  E SÃO, COMO VOCÊ, DESENVOLVEDORES, mas não são gênios, porque eles deveriam "contratar um desenvolvedor"? Porque não podem usar a reputação **ARDUAMENTE** conquistada pra conseguir uma luz quando mais precisam?

E na principal resposta linkada nesta página (do @George Stocker), num comentário (com +18!) está meu principal argumento:

> Mas se temos contribuído bastante para a comunidade para ganhar muitos pontos, por que não estamos autorizados a usufruir esse direito? Eles não estão obstruindo a seção principal, eles estão em uma área de "destaque" que só tem recompensas de qualquer maneira. (livre tradução com ajuda do google, se estiver errado ajustem aí por favor).

Talvez futuramente eu edite esta resposta pra falar sobre o argumento do @George Stocker (manter o método *normal* de perguntar e responder), mas, por hora, este é ponto que queria deixar aqui: precisar oferecer recompensa antes de 48 horas não faz, por si só, que alguém deixe de ser  um desenvolvedor. Tampouco o contrário te faz um grande desenvolvedor.

Uma coisa é uma coisa....

Comment: Acho que temos aqui dois pontos: 1) *"Devemos ter mais beneficios porque já contribuimos muito?"* 2) *"Que problemas pode trazer converter reputação em moeda que beneficia uns mas não outros?"*

Comment: @brasofilo não entendo este ponto: beneficia uns e não outros. Isso não faz sentido pra mim, porque é claro que quem tem pouquíssimos pontos  não contribuiu com o site o bastante pra oferecer recompensa. O prazo pra oferecer recompensa é irrelevante  pra quem não pode oferecer por não ter os pontos... E sobre querer ter mais benefícios, acho que é uma questão de ponto de vista: pra mim é corrigir uma injustiça, que acredito ter sido motivada pelo único argumento que faz sentido (contrate um desenvolvedor), mas que acho injusto e até *irracional*, por prejudicar os próprios desenvolvedores.

Comment: Quem tem 100 pontos já pode oferecer uma recompensa, mas é uma mordida boa na reputação. A princípio, reputação dá privilégios de moderação do site e não de outro tipo. Se o usuário tem 2 ou 3k pode moderar o site a torto e a direito. Para fazer e responder perguntas, se tem 100 pontos vais ser tratado igual quem tem 1 ponto ou cem mil. O principio é o mesmo e a reputação não significa nada.

Comment: Não entendi o "à princípio" @brasofilo... Reputação dá outros privilégios sim. E o mais importante, arrisco a dizer que o único benefício direto, é o oferecimento de recompensa (mas eu tbm curto aquela telinha de perfil que aparece depois de 1k rsrs). Tem o privilégio de votar também, mas fora isso (e deve ter algum que to esquecendo), os privilégios são todos  de moderação. Ou seja, você passa a ter o privilégio de ajudar (ainda mais) o site. E quando você mais precisa dele, toma um "Contrate um desenvovedor!" bem no meio da cara. rsrs.

Comment: E se você tem apenas 1 ponto (ou mesmo 99), você não vai ser tratado igual ao fazer a pergunta, porque em 48 horas  você NÃO poderá oferecer uma recompensa. Então a diferenciação já existe, só o tempo de oferecer é que está em questão. E a razão não é esta (que estamos discutindo agora)...

Comment: O *"contrate"* fui eu quem disse, acho que institucionalmente a frase correta é "tá com pressa? pergunte para seu amigo desenvolvedor". Anyway, lembro você ter comentado que tem formação ou trabalha com Direito... eu também já estudei Direito e trabalhei num TJ, sua resposta tem muito de opinião, quase nada de fato, e nenhuma jurisprudência. Cabe a você provar que o Status Quo está errado. ;)

Comment: Então, "contrate um", "consulte um", dá no mesmo imho: presume-se que quem tem que buscar ajuda não é desenvolvedor. De certa forma, a impressão que fica é que a recompensa só deveria ser utilizada por quem, na prática, não precisa tanto assim da resposta.

Comment: Ah, Gustavo, depende de como você encara a função deste site. Se o problema é urgente ou não, está bem explicado e tem usuários craques atuando na tag em questão, as chances são muito grandes de uma resposta *bloody-professional*, rápida e grátis. Que eu saiba o fundamento do site é "construir uma base de dados de perguntas e respostas de qualidade", não é *"ajudar os desenvolvedores com boa reputação a conseguir respostas rápidas"*.

Comment: @brasofilo Desde o início deste debate **em tese**, tentei deixar bem claro que meu argumento era **apenas sobre este ponto específico** (prazo da recompensa). O SOpt é de longe, mas disparado mesmo, a comunidade mais bem moderada, útil e sensacional de que já participei. E eu respeito a posição do site em querer manter o método normal de perguntar e responder (em que pese achar que ele não seria afetado por um prazo menor de recompensa... algo difícil de mensurar sem um teste), mas ainda acho absurdo o argumento "contrate um desenvolvedor" que apareceu neste tópico. Você ainda acha válido?

Comment: Já vi coisa demais nestes Stacks, gente folgada com 10+ mil pontos de reputação: fácil. Gente que te passa uma lista de desejos e quer sua melhor resposta: vários. Ter muitos pontos só garante que você é raposa velha na casa. Certamente, quem participa de coração e simplesmente pelo prazer de compartir conhecimento fica meio ofendida "puxa, já contribui tanto... por que me tratam como um aproveitador?". Acho que passa um pouco pela idéia "comunitária" que serve de base pro SO e família. (cont.)

Comment: (.cont) Sim, sigo achando válido, foi uma frase que me ocorreu derivada do espírito baiano *"tá com pressa, vá pra São Paulo"*. Aqui não é um site de `é urgente, me dá uma resposta`. É um repositório de conhecimento útil para visitantes futuros, **a pessoa que pergunta não é importante**, o importante é que problema e solução(ões) ajudem outras pessoas. . . . Acho que precisávamos de uma série de traduções de artigos essenciais do [Coding Horror](http://blog.codinghorror.com/), do Metão e do blog da [se]. A série podia se chamar "Por que diacho este site é do jeito que é?".

Comment: Acho que a gente tá falando de coisas diferentes, eu to falando só do prazo pra recompensa. :P

Comment: Eu continuo falando dele, aqui não é lugar para nossas urgências. O tempo de resposta grátis já é fantástico!

Comment: hahaha mas tem duas coisas cara: 1) eu digo que to falando só do prazo da recompensa porque toda hora vc argumenta que tem fulano que é folgado etc..., enquanto eu to falando do prazo em tese, e se for pra pressupor algo, vou pressupor um usuário padrão, um programador profissional (e o complicado é definir este "profissional", à partir de quando ele se torna um...), ou pelo menos um cara estudioso e entusiasta. 2) As perguntas também somam para o site como um todo, sem a pergunta não teria a resposta que vai ser encontrada por futuros users. E ela também é postada sem custo algum. Grátis. ;)

Comment: Vou ser bem direto ao ponto. Se você realmente quer levantar a bandeira da remoção desse prazo, vai ter que ler *tudo* que se discutiu a respeito no Metão, fazer um pedido de [meta-tag:novo-recurso] *muito bem fundamentado*, de preferência em Português e Inglês; melhor ainda se for só Inglês direto no Metão. Não sou eu que você tem que convencer

Comment: kkkkkk Deeeus que me livre! Esqueceu da edição que vc fez na minha resposta? Só entrei nessa porque estava bê-ba-do! kkkkk E como gosto de debater com gente inteligente a coisa foi fluindo e chegamos neste impasse... que já deu mesmo. Bora pra outra. ;)

Comment: lol, jejeje, sim, tinha esquecido da edição, bora lá!