# Mudar contexto de pergunta antiga e não respondida para oferecer recompensa imediata

Tags: debate, comportamento, comunidade, recompensa

É aceito que uma pergunta, antiga, que não houveram respostas, seja editada pelo autor, mudando completamente o contexto?

A ideia de quem faça isso, é para por exemplo, aproveitar o tempo em que a pergunta esteve no ar, para oferecer a recompensa imediata, daí ele não precisaria criar outra, e aguardar 2~3 dias para bonifica-la.

Comment: Tenho certeza que mudar o contexto independente do motivo seja errado, além disto com certeza quem editou não ganhou muita coisa, pois isto dificilmente ajuda em algo, poste a pergunta especifica pra termos certeza do que ocorreu.

Comment: Na verdade não vi ocorrer, trata-se de oportunismo, eu por exemplo, tenho uma questão que preciso de uma resposta mais rápida//qualificada, para isso ofereço uma recompensa, mas ao criar um tópico é me dado 2 dias para bonifica-la, e percebo que tenho algumas perguntas minhas que não foram respondidas, então, mudar o contexto dela e oferecer a recompensa(para atender minha outra pergunta, atual). Seria errado e eu poderia ser punido por isso?

Comment: Relacionado: [Bounty ready reserve questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161392/185667)

Answer (score 11):

O tempo mínimo para oferecer a recompensa tem uma explicação, que foi bem discutida nesse tópico:

[O prazo para poder oferecer uma recompensa é bom?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4427/3117)

Alterar perguntas antigas para oferecer recompensa imediata seria uma forma de tentar se aproveitar de uma brecha no sistema, entretanto, não é por que o sistema permite isso que significa que isso é legal de ser feito.

Qualquer publicação que sofra uma grande distorção de seu contexto dificilmente passa despercebida por todos os usuários do site e é prontamente revertida. Se ela estiver em destaque então eu arriscaria a dizer que essas chances caem para zero.

Tente entender o por que de haver tal restrição por parte de sistema e jogue de acordo com as regras do jogo. Leia o guia [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para aumentar suas chances de conseguir uma boa resposta mais depressa, e sempre fique atento aos comentários dos usuários na sua pergunta pois eles podem dar *feedbacks* valiosos para você melhorar sua pergunta ainda mais.

Sempre que algo não lhe parecer muito certo, lembre-se do seguinte ditado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*"Não é por que você pode que significa que você deve."* :)

Comment: O Oded acha que não tem problema: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166818

Comment: @brasofilo puxa... estou surpreso

Comment: bom, na verdade, a opinião dele não inclui isso de "aproveitar para oferecer recompensa imediata".... ali é o caso de pergunta camaleão que não tem problema

Comment: Ahh tá! Não teve recompensa lá, eu não tinha lido com atenção. Realmente naquele caso acho que é mais simples optar por não fazer nada. Mas usar esse subterfúgio para oferecer recompensa mais rápido eu acho errado.

Comment: +1 Também acho que mudar o sentido de uma pergunta é (ou deveria ser) inaceitável. Só tenho uma correção: a questão no tópico referido ainda não foi muito bem discutida, porque ainda não postei ainda minha resposta lá. hehe

Comment: Eu também não vejo grandes problemas. Ver minha resposta.

Comment: +1 só pela imagem. lol

Answer (score 7):

**NUNCA** mude o contexto, apenas melhore a pergunta.

Existem muitas maneiras de tornar a sua pergunta evidente e as vezes o motivo de não ter resposta é porque ela esta difícil de entender.

Pratique sempre, melhore a maneira de se expressar, pode até mudar todo o texto, **desde** que o contexto seja o mesmo.

Recomendo que siga isto:

- [Perguntas antigas podem ser postadas novamente](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3969/3635)

Answer (score 7):

Se a pergunta não tem nenhuma resposta, eu não vejo problema em mudá-la completamente. Para a grande maioria dos usuários, o resultado final é o mesmo de apagar a pergunta antiga e postar uma nova.

Mas fazer isso para burlar o tempo de espera para oferecer recompensa já muda um pouco a situação. Eu acho tolerável que isso ocorra de vez em quando, mas se alguém começar a fazer isso várias vezes, tenho certeza de que será no mínimo advertido.

Comment: É um ponto de vista. Minha primeira reação foi completamente oposta a essa atitude, mas vou tentar refletir mais sobre isso.